# Avoiding forum style usage and promoting SE style Q and A

Tags: support, answer-format, moderation

There is a [question on the parent site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1444/i-have-problems-installing-ubuntu-10-04) that has become like a forum (follow-up questions and responses posted as answers). The question is complicated because the person asking included several issues together, which txwikinger pointed out in a comment. It does appear to be on-topic, but I'm not sure it is helping anyone in its present state.

Is there anything that can be done to steer that question in a more Stack Exchange Q&A direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, users need to be encouraged to **edit their existing question** (or answer) rather than adding more answers or more questions.

edit, edit, *edit!*

... should be your first impulse, not clicking "new question", or "new answer"

Answer (score 1):

I believe that several questions can be asked in one question so long as they pertain to one specific topic: [This question for instance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868/use-ubuntu-for-a-public-computer-in-a-library/).

However in the case above I think those questions are best suited for each their own topic. As they are each their own issue/question.